# Where is Category Thumbnail Image Display in Magento Default Set up

Tags: magento-1.9

In magento Default Setup when we click on

**catalog >> Manage Categories**

and go for editing any category then we found "**Image**" and "**Thumbnail Image**" File upload button.

When we upload image for "**Image**" Button that image display in Category Page above product listing.

But when we upload image for "**Thumbnail Image**" it is not display on category Page.

Where is magento display that **Thumbnail Image** in default set up. I want to know that.

Answer (score 0):

As per default Magento **Category Thumbnail Image** is not used anywhere.

You can use **Category Thumbnail Image** for your custom showcase.

Generally it is use for category menu, we will show thumbnail image on category menu.